# proc_close has an exit code of 2 on windows server

Tags: php, windows, wkhtmltopdf

I've been using [php wkhtmltopdf](http://mikehaertl.github.io/phpwkhtmltopdf/) and noticed that when using the proc_close function on windows, it returns a value of 2. I've looked for what this exit code means and I can't seem to spot a reference to it. The two codes for proc_close seem to be 0 and -1. I was wondering if anyone could shed some more light on what this error code means. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php) says:

> (proc_close) Returns the termination status of the process that was run. In case of an error then -1 is returned.

So the process returns 2 which is likely an error code. Check the documentation of the process you are calling for the meaning of that error state

Comment: @r1901156 Thank you too, for pointing me towards this tool. I've had a look into the source code. It will return `2` in case the html document was not found (404).. Also there are [PHP bindings](https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox). It might be better to use that bindings than to call the binary